# How to specify a css class when i use an angular component?

Tags: angular, sass, scss-mixins

I am on an angular project and i try to follow the atomic design method and BEM for my CSS structure.

I have atoms components and some have modifier css and i can't use them when i called my component for example :

```
:host{
    .btn {
      padding: 0.7rem 1.7rem;
      border-radius: 1.8rem;
      border-color: transparent;

      &__headerFooter {
        @include btn($color: map.get(map.get( $btnStyle, btnColor), "btnHeaderFooterColor"));
      }
    }
  }
```

When i want to use `headerFooter` in my page where my component is set it isn't work.
I tried different solution but i haven't find a solution yet.

This is my project if you want try it : [my-project](https://github.com/qalimero/single-page-design-portfolio)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the mentioned code in your GitHub project, but from what I can see in your provided code you tried to select `&__headerFooter` which is not a valid scss selector. What exactly are you trying to achieve using these underscores? If 'headerFooter' is just a DOM node inside of the host element, you should replace these underscores with a space:

```
:host{
    .btn {
      padding: 0.7rem 1.7rem;
      border-radius: 1.8rem;
      border-color: transparent;

      & headerFooter {
        @include btn($color: map.get(map.get( $btnStyle, btnColor), "btnHeaderFooterColor"));
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi Fabian,thanks for your reply, i used ```&__headerFooter``` because it's an element from my  block btn, so when i want to call my css class i just have to do ```btn__headerFooter``` on this project i tried to use BEM css method to have a clear syntax